# Convergent of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f \in C^1[0,\infty)$ be an increasing function with $f(0)>0$, suppose $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{f(x)+f'(x)} < \infty$, prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{f(x)} < \infty$.

I find it weird since the behaviour of $f'$ is random, so I don't know how to control $f$ in terms of $f+f'$.

Comment: You ask to prove it, what is the evidence that this is true?

Comment: isn't it just a consequence of $f(x)+f'(x)>f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker no, it seems that it is not

Comment: @FedorPetrov It is an exercise

Comment: In general exercises are not welcome here (although I like this one)

Answer (score 6):

For $a\geqslant 0,b>0$ we have $$\frac1b\leqslant \frac2{a+b}+\frac{a}{b^2}$$
(if $a\leqslant b$, then $\frac1b\leqslant \frac2{a+b}$; if $a\geqslant b$, then $\frac1b\leqslant \frac{a}{b^2}$). Apply this for $b=f$, $a=f'$ and use that $\int f'/f^2=\int (-1/f)'$ converges.